# Binding a control property to an expression

Tags: asp.net, webforms

With ASP.NET WebForms, is it possible to bind a control's property to an expression?

For example

```
Visible="<% myProp.Value == otherProp.Value %>"
```

I realize I can do this in the code-behind, but I'm trying to keep UI display details confined to the markup as much as possible.

Comment: `Visible='<%# myProp.Value == otherProp.Value %>'` (databinding expression)

Comment: I've tried this, but doesn't appear to work.  Although what I'm attempting to evaluate is two other controls on the page.  One is the HiddenField's value comparing against a div's ID (and the div is set to runat=server).  If I do this in the code behind all works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and this is the most efficient way to do ASP.Net WebForms development.

You want to call `DataBind()` to make the `<%# myProp.Value == otherProp.Value %>` expression to be evaluated. I prefer calling `DataBind()` in `Page_PreRender`

Example:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# myProp.Value == otherProp.Value %>'>
  Hello
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In fact, you can put your databinding logic either in your base class for your page, or in a `<script runat="server">` block.

Complete page example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
   void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DataBind();
   }
</script>
<html>
 <body>
  <asp:Placeholder runat="server" Visible='<%# DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 1 %>'>
   It is now an odd second
  </asp:Placeholder>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neat!  I did not know you could place page class methods in a server script tag.